# Create directory on Windows and check if it exists

Tags: c++, windows

I have to create some directories and when I try to search one I have to know if it was already created.

The problem is that after creating a directory with `CreateDirectory()` and trying to check if it was created I get an error which says that it wasn't created.

If I close and restart the program, without creating the directory but just checking if it was created, everything works.

```
bool DirectoryExists( const char* absolutePath ){
    if( _access( absolutePath, 0 ) == 0 ){
        struct stat status;
        stat( absolutePath, &status );
        return (status.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;
    }
    return false;
}

marca = "database\\"+marca;
CreateDirectory (marca.c_str(), NULL);
// useless operation
if(! DirectoryExists(marca.c_str() )  )
{
    cout<<" Error !";
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: You're not checking the result of `CreateDirectory`.  If that is a function you wrote yourself, you should include it in the sample above.  (As-is, your code will not properly compile, at least because `DirectoryExists` is not declared before it is used.)  You should also give information about your system / OS, because you're including a backslash in the directory name.  Different systems handle slashes and backslashes differently -- it's possible that you're trying to make a directory with an invalid name.

Comment: Sorry, CreateDirecotry() it is not my function i think It is a system call of Windows. I am using Windows 10 as OS

Comment: You should still check the return value, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createdirectory). It returns 0 on failure and you can check the reason with the GetLastError function.

Comment: Why are you using relative paths?

Comment: If a directory already exists, calling `CreateDirectory()` for it will return `FALSE` and then `GetLastError()` will return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.  This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya).  But, you should be using absolute paths instead of relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

If `marca` was "database" it would work. But if `marca` is "database/foo" you cannot create *both* of these at the same time.

Here's a version of your code where I separate these operations.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool DirectoryExists( const char* absolutePath )
{
    if( _access( absolutePath, 0 ) == 0 ){

        struct stat status;
        stat( absolutePath, &status );

        return (status.st_mode & S_IFDIR) != 0;
    }
    return false;
}

bool MakeDirectory(const string& marca)
{
    if(! CreateDirectory(marca.c_str(), NULL))
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        TCHAR buf[256];
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), 
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(TCHAR)), NULL);
        cout << "Failed to create directory: " << buf << '\n';
        return false;
    }

    if(! DirectoryExists(marca.c_str() )  )
    {
        cout << "Directory does not exist\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    // name of subdirectory
    string marca = "foo"; 

    // first create top directory
    string d = "database";
    MakeDirectory(d);

    // then subdirectory
    d += "/" + marca;
    MakeDirectory(d);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but the folder "database" was already created

Comment: You are not handling the case where `CreateDirectory()` fails with an `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` error for an existing directory. That is not a failure, so don't treat it as one. And there is no good reason to call `DirectoryExists()` inside of `MakeDirectory()` at all. The result of `CreateDirectory()` is sufficient.

Comment: I would suggest moving the logic to create the intermediate sub-directories into `MakeDirectory()` itself so that you can pass it a full path and it can call `CreateDirectory()` in a loop for each intermediate sub-directory. Or, replace `CreateDirectory()` with [`SHCreateDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shcreatedirectory) instead, which handles that for you.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it was my error because I am stupid. I used che command SetCurrentDirectory() so my directory was different every time. For this the program says that the folder doesn't exist and for this reason when I close the program and restart it worked.